# * "<: None>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used * this error is not caught by exception handling

Tags: python, django, exception, admin

I am trying to throw a error by not saving the id of many to many field and trying to reach the except block but it is still throwing the value error. The except block is not called.

```
try:
        def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
            stop = False
            print("test2")
            if "_stop" in request.POST:
                stop = True
                obj.save()
            state_id = request.POST.getlist('state')
            get_homescommunity_data(request, state_id, stop)
    except ValueError:
        print("test1")
        redirect("/admin/newhomedata/communitypagesurl/")
```

Comment: You define the function but never call it. The function is not executed in the `try/except` block.

Comment: I am calling a function "get_homescommunity_data(request, state_id, stop)" which is made in views.py which is storing my data but this save_model add another none field as it has to save some data. I was tring to truncate it before it gives None. what should I do?